# Create Update Trigger To Copy Changed Data In MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER backupFIDE AFTER UPDATE ON player
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.FIDERating <> NEW.FIDERating) THEN
INSERT INTO playerbackup(PlayerName, OldFIDERating, NewFIDERating)
VALUES(OLD.PlayerName, OLD.FIDERating, NEW.NewFIDERating)
END;
```

Hi guys, receiving syntax error at line 6 for some reason, been looking online for solution to what might be the cause. Basically looking a simple trigger, that will copy a change change of FIDERating in Player table to a backup table containing OldFIDERating before it was changed, and the NewFIDERating along with the date change was made.

Comment: I have tried DELIMITER still same issue, also set DATABASE.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER backupFIDE AFTER UPDATE ON player
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.FIDERating <> OLD.FIDERating
THEN
INSERT INTO playerbackup(PlayerName, OldFIDERating, NewFIDERating)
VALUES(OLD.PlayerName, OLD.FIDERating, NEW.NewFIDERating);
END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```